# How to calculate optimal tuple size in Elastic Search bulk insert

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I am inserting data in Elasticsearch from python. The data is analysed and stored in pandas dataframe. The dataframe is converted into dict and then to tuple, to insert data. This works but it sometimes gives timeout error. I was looking for ways to avoid timeout.

```
es = Elasticsearch([target_elasticSearchUrl])
j = helpers.bulk(es,tuple(insert_df.to_dict(orient='records')), index = target_index,doc_type='doc')
```

So, I tried restricting tuple size to 500, which reduced the timeout instances, but it impacted performance drastically. As I have more than 1 million records to upload.

I am looking for ways to avoid performance impact or another way to insert data in Elasticsearch other than the bulk insert.

Comment: Hello, you can use requests module to do so.

Comment: May you please provide the exception exactly as you get it? Looks like [`bulk()`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.bulk) helper is the way to go, it should do the job of chunking underneath.